# Number constraints in JSON Schema Validation

Tags: json, numbers, constraints, jsonschema

I am working of JSON Schema Validation. I wanted to know if it is possible to impose number constraints, and if it is possible, how.

For example:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/simpleSchema",
    "properties": {
        "birthYear": {
            "type":"number"
        },
        "deathYear": {
            "type":"number"
        },
        "name": {
            "type":"string"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
birthYear <= deathYear
```

How can I do this? Is there a specific keyword for constraints like these?

Thank you very much.

João

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON Schema does not support constraints that refer to other properties.

See [5.1. Validation keywords for numeric instances (number and integer)](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor13) for what is possible.